# Where are the archives stored for OS X server bots

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-server

I'm running Mavericks Server and using bots for CI.  Some of my bots create an archive when run.  Since I have a finite of drive space, I want to be sure that I don't overfill the machine with archives and ipa files.

Where are these files stored, and is it possible to change this location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it [here](http://matt.vlasach.com/xcode-bots-hosted-git-repositories-and-automated-testflight-builds/).

It turns out that the builds, including the archives, are stored at the following location.

`/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/`

EDIT:

For Xcode Server 5.0.1 / Xcode 7 GM and beyond, see primulaveris's answer.

Comment: As of Xcode Server 5.0.1 and Xcode 7 GM this is no longer correct. The answer by primulaveris is correct.

Answer (score 8):

Yosemite server stores them in
`/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets/`
There is a directory for each bot, containing all the build products and archives generated by it.

Comment: It disturbs me that this directory is not "officially" accessible anywhere—there does not seem to be an "Open in Finder" option.

Answer (score 5):

For Xcode 7.0 / Server 5.0.4 we have the following situation:

1. Xcode server provides an environment variable XCS_ARCHIVE which can be accessed within an "After integration" trigger script. This variable holds the path to the archive generated during an "integration".
2. Shortly after the execution of the "After integration" trigger this archive is moved to a different place. Put this snippet into an "After integration" trigger to see the actual pathes:

```
    TARGET_NAME=`basename "${XCS_ARCHIVE}" .xcarchive`
    INTEGRATION_ASSETS=/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets/

    IPA_PATH=${INTEGRATION_ASSETS}/${XCS_BOT_ID}-${XCS_BOT_NAME}/${XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER}/${TARGET_NAME}.ipa
    ARCHIVE_PATH=${INTEGRATION_ASSETS}/${XCS_BOT_ID}-${XCS_BOT_NAME}/${XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER}/${TARGET_NAME}.xcarchive.zip

    echo ${IPA_PATH}
    echo ${ARCHIVE_PATH}
```

3. It is important to know, that `${ARCHIVE_PATH}` as well `${IPA_PATH}` from the script above are not yet available during execution of the "After Integration" trigger. They are moved to its place shortly after execution.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX-Server 5.3 (16S4123), XCode 8.3.2 (8E2002):
`/Users/<xcode_server_tester_user_name>/Library/Caches/XCSBuilder/Bots/`